# Q (KDB) selecting today's date within date range

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I am trying to set up an dynamic threshold by different user, but only return result from today's date. I was able to return all the records from past 30 days, but I am having trouble only outputting today's date based on the calculation from past 30 days.. I am new to q language and really having a trouble with this simple statement :( (have tried and/or statement but not executing..) Thank you for all the help in advance!

```
select user, date, real*110 from table where date >= .z.D - 30,   real> (3*(dev;real) fby user)+((avg;real) fby user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to determine if any of todays "real" values are greater than 3 sigma based on the past 30 days? If so (without knowing much about your table structure) I'm guessing you could use something like this:

```
q)t:t,update user:`user2,real+(.0,39#10.0) from t:([] date:.z.D-til 40;user:`user1;real:20.1,10.0+39?.1 .0 -.1);

q)sigma:{avg[y]+x*dev y};

q)select from t where date>=.z.D-30, ({(.z.D=x`date)&x[`real]>sigma[3]exec real from x where date<>.z.D};([]date;real)) fby user
date       user  real
---------------------
2016.03.21 user1 20.1
```